# Error when using Google Application Default Credentials on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am trying to make a Node.js app (running Express on App Engine) authenticate with Google API (Server-to-Server) using the [Google Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials). The app is supposed to use the credentials to talk with Google Analytics, which I have set up by turning on the `Analytics API` in the `Google Developers Console`. This is the code I have implemented:

```
var google = require('googleapis')
var analytics = google.analytics('v3')

app.post('/getAnalyticsData', (req, res) => {
  google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function(err, authClient) {
    if (err) {
      /* Handle error */
    }
    if (authClient) {
      if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
        authClient = authClient.createScoped(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'])
      }
      analytics.data.ga.get({
        'auth': authClient,
        'ids': 'ga:VIEW_ID',
        'metrics': 'ga:pageviews,ga:sessions',
        'start-date': '2017-01-01',
        'end-date': '2017-03-09'
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Analytics error: ", err)
        }
        if (response) {
          console.log("YAY! Analytics response: ", response)
          /* Do something with the response */
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

But I am getting this error: `A Forbidden error was returned while attempting to retrieve an access token for the Compute Engine built-in service account. This may be because the Compute Engine instance does not have the correct permission scopes specified. Insufficient Permission`.

Any idea how to solve this and succeed with the authentication?

Comment: I have this exact same problem. did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to use google-auth-library to connect to datastore and was unable to set the correct permissions for the default service account. I found an [example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/samples/keyfile.js) in their samples folder that created an auth client using a key file. You can create your own service account with the right permissions and generate a key file on the [service account admin page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) in the cloud console. Hope this helps.

```
const {auth} = require('google-auth-library');

async function getDnsInfo() {
  const client = await auth.getClient({
    keyFile: 'path/to/keyFile.json,
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
  });
  const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${projectId}`;
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.log('DNS Info:');
  console.log(res.data);
}
```